# Does converting a file to base64 the best way to send it to front-end?

Tags: c#

I've been wondering if converting a file from a directory into a base64 string the best way to send it to front-end?

I have a function that converts file into a base64 string. It converts images perfectly, however, files such as `.doc` or `.xlsx` gave me a wrong base64 string or I dont know if it's wrong because when I tried to [convert](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/file) it to file.... it gives me error saying `Your browser cannot display the file as “application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet”.`

Here's the result for : **(I will only post the first chunk of the base64 string)**

`.xlsx`

```
UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQBi7p1oXgEAAJAEAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAACAAAAAAAAA
```

`.doc`

```
0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOwADAP7/CQAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAvwAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAgAAAAEAAAD+////AAAAAAAAAACAAAAA///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////9//////////7///8OAAAABQA
```

Comment: The browser has support for embedding an image as base64 encoded right into the html, but it does not handle any other formats in this manner. As such, to download a working Excel worksheet file, you need to supply the original bytes in the file, unmodified, unencoded.

Comment: B64 encode is a + 33% in zize. But what is you real question? Do you have a code that cause an error?

Comment: Base64 is a good way to communicate and send binary data between a client and a server. That being said, your issue is not with base64. The browser only supports certain formats and headers and XLSX and DOC are not part of that. In order to display those is to first convert them to a browser supported format such as PNG or JPEG. You can use a library that supports converting these 2 formats and encode them as base 64. You can read more here: https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t12748- as a disclaimer, I am an employee of this library.